# JQuery - Populating selection list from database using JDBC

Tags: jquery, jsp, jdbc

I need to populate in my .jsp file selection from database. As you may see, I build the selection using JQuery (I've created the form earlier and now just append things).

I hoped to use something like this:

```
    <%
    // Connection to DB using JDBC 
    %>
        <script>
        //JS code here
            $form.append('Enter city name: '
                +'<select id="location">' 
                <%
                    for(i=0;i<rowsNum;i++) {
                    out.println("+'<option>"+cities.get(i)+" - "+streets.get(i)+"</option>'");
                }                   
                %>
                +'</select>');
        //JS code here
        </script>
    <%
    //Connection close
    %>
```

but it doesn't work. A brief search didn't help much.

Is the problem in this particular part of the code, or it's something else and this part is OK?

Thanks!

Comment: "but it doesn't work" - In what way doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally clumsy , why have you combine **scriptlets** with **script** . scriptlets are java codes and these are executed on you server . while jquery is the client side java script library .

You can use ajax to get the values from the datebase and populating it in the servlet.

using java codes in jsp is considered as bad practice see this [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Welcome:) Try that and comment here if you have any trouble in that